# Problem in the proof of the Second Sylow Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm missing a detail in the following proof of the Second Sylow Theorem:

> Let G be a finite group and p a divisor of $|G|$. Let $|G| = p^km$
>   with $p \nmid m$. Then if $H \le G$ is a p-subgroup then there exists
>   $P \le G$ p-subgroup such that $H \le P$.

The proof begins with a lemma which goes as follows (I put it here for completeness):

> Let $P$ be a p-subgroup of Sylow of $G$ and $H \le G$ a p-subgroup
>   such that $H \le N_G(P)$ then $H \le P$.

The proof of theorem goes as follows:

Let $S$ be the set of p-subgroups of Sylow and let's take the conjugation action of $G$ on $S$. Let $P_1 \in S$  be a p-subgroup and $T = O(P_1)$ be the orbit of such p-subgroup then I understand the following facts:

1. $P_1 \trianglelefteq N_G(P_1) \le G$ and therefore $[G:P_1] = [G:N_G(P_1)][N_G(P_1):P_1]$

but I don't understand why

2. $[G:P_1] = m$

which should lead to the fact that $p \nmid |T| = [G:N_G(P_1)]$.

I'd say that it is really simple but I'm stuck, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $P_1$ was chosen from the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups, so

$$[G:P_1]=\vert G\vert / \vert P_1\vert$$

And as $P_1$ is a $p$-Sylow, $\vert P_1\vert=p^k$, so that lets you what you want.

The point of $p\not\mid [G:N_G(P_1)]$ is because $P_1\leq N_G(P_1)$, so $\vert N_G(P_1)\vert= p^kr$ with $1\leq r\leq m$, so again:

$$[G:N_G(P_1)]=\vert G\vert / \vert N_G(P_1)\vert=m/r$$

That is prime to $p$.

Comment: I just missed the definition of p-Sylow...thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If it's possible, can you tell me where are you reading that proof?

Comment: I'm just writing the notes I had from class the most similar proof to what i have is in jacobson's book. i've written a draft in latext which you can see here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92679781/segundoteoremasylow.pdf

Comment: Se ven bastante bien, aunque no entiendo cómo haces la diferencia entre el primer teorema de Sylow, el segundo y el tercero, porque el tercer punto de tus notas dice "tercer teorema de Sylow". ¿No sería bueno separarlos?// They look pretty good, but I don't understand how you do the difference between the first Sylow theorem, the second and the third, because the third point of your notes says "third Sylow's theorem". It won't be better separate both?

Comment: That's why I said that I believe my professor followed jacobson's proof because in his book there are only two Sylow theorems whereas in Fraleigh's and Dummit's books there are three theorems. I just noted it because it can be confusing to people that read from one book to another. I had a similar situation with isomorphism theorems, depending on the book you read you'll find different numbers for the theorems. Thanks for the advice anyway!!